# How to map control-f back in vs.net?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, viemu

I installed viemu, and now `control-F` and **copy/past shortcuts** are not working.

How can I fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable the combinations in the settings

[image]

Comment: what does control C, F and H do in VIM?

Comment: `Ctrl+C` is similar to Escape, `Ctrl+F` like pagedown, in insert mode `Ctrl+H` is Backspace

Comment: where is that popup? sorry can't find it, maybe you need a license?

Comment: I don't have that menu in Tools | Options.